# Convexity of an exponential function.

Tags: random-variables, convex-analysis

A random variable $Y_i$ is given such that, $\mid$Y$_i\mid$$\leq$ $c_i$ where i ranges from 1,.....,t and t is some constant. Now, $Y_i$ is expressed as :

$Y_i = ((Y_i - c_i) + (Y_i + c_i))/2$

$= -c_i(1-Y_i/c_i)/2  + c_i(1+Y_i/c_i)/2$

Using the convexity of $e$<sup>kY<sub>i</sub></sup> where k is some constant,

$e$<sup>kY<sub>i</sub></sup> $\leq$ $0.5*(1 - Y_i/c_i)$ $e$<sup>-kc<sub>i</sub></sup> + $0.5*(1 + Y_i/c_i)$ $e$<sup>kc<sub>i</sub></sup>

Can you please explain how did the author arrive at this conclusion? And what exactly did he do when he used the convexity of the exponential function?
Also, I am not sure as to what to tag this question under, So if you have an objection with my tags, kindly suggest the appropriate tags so that I can edit them accordingly.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If f is convex, $f(\alpha a + \beta b) \le \alpha f(a) + \beta f(b)$
where two nonnegative coefficents $\alpha \ge 0$, and $\beta \ge 0$ $$\alpha + \beta = 1$$

Now let $\alpha = 0.5*(1 - Y_i/c_i)$ and $\beta = 0.5*(1 + Y_i/c_i)$
and $ a = -kc_i$, and $b = kc_i$

and $f = e^x$

$$ e^{kYi} = e^{(1-Y_i/c_i)/2 (-kc_i)  + (1+Y_i/c_i)/2 (kc_i)}$$
$$\le \alpha e^{-kc_i} + \beta e^{kc_i}$$
$$= 0.5*(1 - Y_i/c_i) e^{-kc_i} + 0.5*(1 + Y_i/c_i) e^{kc_i}$$